# How to implement the table-style layout with ASP.NET, Javascript solution

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

We got a requirement to implment following structure of table (It's a sample; data source is dynamic). Notice that there are intermediate **Total** (sum) values for the month.

If we have the data source (Date and Amount) besides Total, which is calculated out, do you have any suggestion to generate this kind of table-style layout dynamitcally?

```
Date     Amount
==========================
1  Nov   300
22 Nov   500
30 Nov   200
Total    1000
5  Dec   100
28 Dec   200
Total    300
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking? How HTML works? How ASP.NET works?

Comment: I mean dynamically generating the table-styke UI based on data source (Date and Amount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a repeater for that. Mind you, this solution is only an example and can be improved in many ways.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDatabound="myRepeater_Databound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd MMM}") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Amount") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trMonthlyTotal" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><asp:Literal id="ltMontlyTotal" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Then, in your codebehind:

```
int currentMonth = 0;
int monthlyTotal = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtDataSource = GetData();
    myRepeater.DataSource = dtDataSource;
    myRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void myRepeater_Databound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataView dv = e.Item.DataItem as DataView;
        DateTime currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dv["Date"]);

        if (currentDate.Month != currentMonth && currentMonth != 0)
        {
            HtmlTable trMonthlyTotal = e.Item.FindControl("trMonthlyTotal") as HtmlTableRow;
            Literal ltMonthlyTotal = e.Item.FindControl("ltMonthlyTotal") as Literal;

            trMonthlyTotal.Visible = true;
            ltMontlyTotal = Convert.ToString(monthlyTotal);

            currentMonth = currentDate.Month;
            monthlyTotal = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            monthlyTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dv["Amount"]);
            if (currentMonth == 0) currentMonth = currentDate.Month;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is only about the layout, than it should be pretty simple, as the 'total' rows have the same number of cells as all the others. By simply applying a CSS class to those rows, you can make them distinguishable.

The question is, how'll the data be retrieved? Would it include the totals as well, or does it have to be calculated on the fly?

If it has to be a running total, than you could use a GridView,Repeater or a ListView to create the table, and sign up to the control's OnItemDataBound/OnRowDataBound event, to calculate it. I'm sure you can access the values through the DataItem, available in these events, an by comparing the current row's month to the previous one, you know when to insert the total row, and reset your counter.

Answer (score 1):

You may get ideas from here:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var data =[
            {d:1, m:'nov', a:300},
            {d:22, m:'nov', a:500},
            {d:30, m:'nov', a:20},          
            {d:5, m:'dec', a:1000},
            {d:28,m:'dec', a:200},
            {d:9,m:'dec', a:300}
        ];

        var total = 0 ;
        var prev='';

        var htm = [];
        htm.push('<table border="1">');
        htm.push('<tr><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>');
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var d = data[i].d;
            var m = data[i].m;
            var a = data[i].a;

            if(prev!='' && prev!=m){
                htm.push('<tr style="font-weight:bold;"><td>Total</td><td>' + total + '</td></tr>');
                total = 0;
            }
            total = total + a;
            prev = m;

            htm.push('<tr><td>' + d + ' ' + m + '</td><td>' + a + '</td></tr>');            
        }
        htm.push('<tr style="font-weight:bold;"><td>Total</td><td>' + total + '</td></tr>');
        htm.push('</table>');

        document.write(htm.join(''));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/). Additionally there is a very nice plugin with which you could easily implement a nicely seperated template: [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/). The advantage is that you can lazily load the data through a WebService.

But as Gidon comments, you could easily achieve wanted behaviour by simply using standard asp.net mechanisms and build the table server side, eg. with a nested Repeater/DataGrid or whatever datacontrol.

with kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Why the need for Javascript? It's tabular data, use a table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1 Nov</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22 Nov</td>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>30 Nov</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Total</th>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5  Dec</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>28 Dec</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Total</th>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not 100% sure on the semantics of the row headers, but I'm pretty sure that is correct.

Comment: Sorry, the data source is dynamic, not static. How do I dynamically generate the table-style UI.